# One section will be image and other section is text(H1,P,Span)

Tags: html, css, frontend, tags

what sematic tags we will use?
Can we use non sematic tags within sematic tags is it good to write clean code?
Like this.

```
<section>
    <div>
      
    </div>
 </section>
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M378A.png)

I tried doing like this
I used

```
<main>
    <section>
    </section>
    <section>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: You can use any tag you like, semanitc tags like section, nav, header, footer, article and aside don't have any special qualities but they do help accessibility softfware know what the purpose of the content is.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.